# Workaround for AWS KMS request per second limit

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a high speed transaction application. KMS request per second is limited which caused issue with my transaction application. Is there a way of prevent this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can always contact AWS support to increase your limits.

Else, as per AWS documentation, only solution recommend as of now is Data Key caching.

> Caching can reduce your use of cryptographic services, such as AWS Key
>   Management Service (AWS KMS). If you are hitting your AWS KMS
>   requests-per-second limit, caching can help. Your application can use
>   cached keys to service some of your data key requests instead of
>   calling AWS KMS. (You can also create a case in the AWS Support Center
>   to raise the limit for your account.)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/data-key-caching.html

Answer (score 0):

AWS libraries uses GenerateDataKey operation to fetch the KMS key in all places.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_GenerateDataKey.html

Raise request with AWS to increase GenerateDataKey throttle limit to increase the rate limit threshold.